# Steps to find $\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^n+3n!}{n^n+(3n)!} = 0$

Tags: limits, factorial

I don't understand why $\lim_\limits{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^n+3n!}{n^n+(3n)!} = 0$

It's taken from **Basisboek wiskunde** (`8.22d`) from *Jan van de Craats*.

The solution given is:

> $0$ (because $(3n)! = n! \times (n+1)(n+2)...3n>n! \times n^n$, etc.)

Actually, I don't understand this answer at all, I'd need some more steps to get it, could someone help me to make it clearer ?

Comment: The multiplication $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)$ is not smaller than $n^n$.  Does that help?

Comment: @abiessu where does $(n+n)$ come from ?

Comment: It is one of the terms in the sequence $n+1,n+2,n+3,\dots,2n-1,2n,2n+1,\dots$

Comment: @abiessu Why $(3n)!$ is equal to $n! \times (n+1)(n+2)...3n$ ?

Comment: That's the definition of a factorial, all the terms in the sequence are multiplied.

Comment: Also because $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$(3n)! = n! \times (n+1)(n+2)...(3n) > n! \times \underbrace{(n)(n)...(n)}_{\text{2n times}} = n! \times n^{2n} \geq n! \times n^n$.

The key step above is replacing $n+1$ , $n+2$ , $n+3$ etc with $n$ each time.

Thus we have:

$$\frac{n^n+3n!}{n^n+(3n)!} < \frac{n^n+3n!}{n^n + (n! \times n^n)}$$

Can you finish it up from here?

Comment: I don't understand this equality $(3n)! = n! \times (n+1)(n+2)...(3n)$

Comment: No worries, so you know that factorial of a number $n$ is the product of all numbers less than or equal to $n$. For example, $4! = 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$. So $(3n)!$ is the product of all numbers less than or equal to $3n$, thus $(3n)! = (3n) \times (3n-1) \times (3n-2) \times ... \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$. We also have $n! = n \times (n-1) \times ... \times 2 \times 1$ so we can write $(3n!) = (3n) \times (3n-1) \times \; ... \times \; \underbrace{n \times (n-1) \times \; ... 2 \times 1}_{\text{this is the }n!\text{ bit}} = (3n) \times (3n-1) \times \; ... \times \; (n+1) \times n!$

Comment: It's maybe easier to see with an example, let $n=3$, so that $3n=9$. So $9! = 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 9 \times 8 \times ... \times 4 \times \underbrace{3 \times 2 \times 1}_{\text{this is }3!} = 9 \times 8 \times ... \times 4 \times 3!$

Comment: Clear! Many thanks!!